# Django E-learning Platform modeling

Tags: django, django-models, blogs

I am  making an E-learning web application/Blog  and I have 2 models: Courses and Chapters, so obviously a course  can   have multiple chapters, but  what I want to do is let's say  I have a course with 12 chapters  I want to group the chapters into parts without creating another model exemple:

Course: Exemple_Course

- Part 01: 5 chapters
- Part 02: 5 chapters
- Part 03: 2 chapters

this is my code  :

```
class Article(models.Model):


    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    title         = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description   = models.TextField()
    slug          = models.SlugField(blank=True,null=True,)
    date          =  models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True)
    allowed_subscription = models.ManyToManyField(Plan,blank=True, null=True,)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('articles:article-detail', kwargs={'article_slug': self.slug})


def pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)



pre_save.connect(pre_save_receiver, sender=Article)




CHAPTER_TYPES = (
        ('CHAPTER', 'Chapter'),
        ('SUB_CHAPTER', 'Sub chapter'),
       
    )


class Chapter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug          = models.SlugField(blank=True,null=True,)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,)
    content  = models.TextField()
    chapter_type  = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=CHAPTER_TYPES)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.title
    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('articles:chapter-detail', kwargs={'article_slug': self.article.slug,'chapter_slug': self.slug,})



pre_save.connect(pre_save_receiver, sender=Chapter)
```

Answer (score 1):

While it makes sense to make another model, another way to deal with that is to add another field "part" on your model, have a shared key for your courses (like name) and create a unique_together constraint.

Doing so, you logically create a "composite primary key" on your models (being (course_name, part).

Comment: @thanks i will try that and see if it works